# Using jQuery .on() method doesn't work on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, anchor

I am currently working on a website that has a logout button which gets dynamically inserted into a sidebar whenever the window reaches a certain size. When I click on the log out button I want to call the method `logOut();`

The ID of the anchor tag is "btnLogOut" everywhere(even checked it by searching in my IDE in case there are any invisible characters or something).

There is always only one log out anchor tag on every page. To be sure, I replaced "btnLogOut" with "btnLogOut_zq" everywhere and the error persisted.

I used `setInterval(function(){ console.log($("#btnLogOut").length); },1);` and this returns 1 constantly while resizing the window and making it bigger and then smaller and so on so the element is always present on the page.

Using `.on()` method to detect a click and then call `logOut();` method

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on("click", "#btnLogOut", function()
    {
        logOut();
    });
});
```

This is what I use to take the original anchor tag and put it in the sidebar(Only the part that's relevant to the logout button):

```
$.fn.navList = function() {

    var $this = $(this);
        $a = $this.find('a'),
        b = [];

    $a.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
            href = $this.attr('href'),
            target = $this.attr('target');
        if($a.attr("id") === "btnLogOut") {
            console.log($a);
            b.push(
                '<a ' +
                    'id="btnLogOut" ' + 
                    'class="link depth-' + indent + '"' +
                    ( (typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
                    ( (typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
                '>' +
                    $this.text() +
                '</a>'
            );
        }

    });

    return b.join('');

};
```

```
$(
    '<div id="navPanel">' +
        '<nav>' +
            $('#btns').navList() +
        '</nav>' +
    '</div>'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating elements by string does not "instantiate" them inside of the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). To get around this you would have to create the elements by means of the DOM's Javascript API (or serverside rendering of elements before the DOM loads, EG: an HTML file).

Although there are a few ways to do it, this is a good example with jQuery:

```
b.push(
    $('<a />', {id:"btnLogout", class: "link depth-1", target:"_BLANK", "href":"HTTP://", "text":$this.text()})
);
```

Assuming `b` is an existing array that'll be appended to another element or iterated over.

Learn more about creating elements the "correct" way on the Mozilla docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

EDIT:

For your nesting further down:

```
$('<div />', {id: 'navPanel'}).append(
    $('<nav />', html: $("#btns").navList())
);
```

If you have access to ES6 then you can use Template Literals for this:

```
$(
    `<div id="navPanel">
        <nav>
            $($('#btns').navList())
        </nav>'
    </div>`
)
```

I'm not sure if the syntax will conflict with the jQuery shorthand dollar sign.

Comment: the `navList()` method returns each element of `b` separated by `' '` which then gets appended to the body in another script (the third code block of the question). Substituting your code with mine just makes the words `[object Object]` appear in my sidebar after resizing. Do I now need to use this jQuery way for the whole process or is there a way to make this work so it gets appended together with all other nav elements (everything else works fine because they are all anchor tags with hrefs)?

Comment: If you are in a position to make use of ES6 functionality then your alternative could be to use [template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). I've also updated my response to contain further information to answer your reply with both scenarios.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how the string literals could help me. What about the jQuery solution or `createElement()`? I can't be the first person in the world that dynamically inserted an anchor tag that should call a method into a sidebar. This shouldn't be so overwhelming, right?

Comment: It is the correct way to create elements, you can't insert by string once the DOM has been initialized. I also noticed two additional things that I accidentally left out. 1. You may need to create the event listener after the elements have been created, although that depends on your library/api. 2. You can't use the same IDs for multiple elements, use classes instead.

Comment: Which one of the three solutions is the correct way to create elements? 1. I tried pasting the "event listener"(first code block) into the console after creating the element for the second time and it still doesn't work. 2. As per my question, the return value of `setInterval(function(){ console.log($("#btnLogOut").length); },1);` is constantly 1, so I'm not using the same ID on multiple elements, right?

Comment: I assumed because of the loop (`$a.each()`) that you were allowing the creation of duplicate IDs. In your case, since you are using jQuery, the jQuery solution would work great. [Here's an implemented sample](https://mordhaumaps.com/main.js?v=1.0) (from line 152).

Comment: I used the if to make sure that only the logout button gets the `btnLogOut` ID. There is an else that lets all other anchor tags get created without an ID. How should I go about only getting `[object Object]` after using the jQuery code you provided me?

Comment: If you could provide a working JSfiddle to your main question, I would happily assist you!

Comment: I already have Firebase Hosting set up: https://luana-72d14.web.app/main.html. util.js is where the file where the anchor becomes another anchor and then in main.js it gets appended to the body. After you make the window smaller, the logout button from the top right-hand side gets added to the "dropotron" that you can activate by clicking on the top left-hand side of the page.

Comment: I commented out `$('#btns').navList() +` and added `$('<div />', {id: 'navPanel'}).append($('<nav />', html: $("#btns").navList()));` after the .appendTo($body) so the logout button gets added to the dropotron after the main navbar but after doing this I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error on the line of code that should add the logout button.

Answer (score 0):

Just put:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnLogOut", function()
{
   logOut();
});
```

Outside the `$(document).ready`

Careful, because by looking at your HTML page code, you have two times the ID `#btnLogOut`.

**EDIT 1:**

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x8aumd0/3/) that I created in order to show you that even elements created on the fly have the `onclick` event attached.

Comment: I wish it were that easy but this doesn't work, either.

Comment: I see that it works but it doesn't work in my case. You can read the chain of comments between me and @Matt to see what I tried until now and where I am situated in my spiral into madness.

Comment: Well, I already told you that you have two ID in your HTML page code called `#btnLogOut` and you're not allowed to have that. You have not yet understand the hint. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: I changed the ID to a class everywhere in my sources and I get the same result. I don't think this would have been a problem before, though, as I always only had one `#btnLogOut` on the page at every given time (proven by the fact that `setInterval(function(){ console.log($("#btnLogOut").length); },1);` only returns 1.